# Macron in section heading merges into letter

Tags: libertine

I have a section heading that includes the word 'erōs'. I currently have a command mapped which replaces `\eros` with `er\=os`, thus printing the macron. The problem is that in the heading, which is bold, the macron is effectively swallowed up into the 'o'. Is there any way to print it a little higher? I am currently using `libertine` font, btw.

edit - MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Macron}{Macr\=on\xspace}

\begin{document}
\section{\Macron Problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your example, it looks just fine.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's annoying. I use shareLaTex.com. I'll try compiling on miktex at some point

Comment: For me the appearance is fine as long as I don't zoom out too far.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a version issue. You can detect the used version very simple with the package `dateiliste` and printing the version in your document. Therefor you can use the following example:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[showpages, svn]{dateiliste}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Macron}{Macr\=on\xspace}

\begin{document}
\section{\Macron Problem}

\printFileList[\subsubsection]
\end{document}
```

It needs two compilation runs.

The important line is the version of `libertine.sty`.

With TeX Live 2013 you get:

```
libertine.sty 0 2013/02/13
```

whereby ShareLaTeX is using

```
libertine.sty 0 2011/06/06
```